# Understand the generalized eigenvalue solvers in LAPACK in Fortran

Tags: fortran, lapack

I tried to solve a generalized eigenvalue problem for both eigenvalue and eigenvectors, at least for the lowest one.

`A x = lambda B x`

where `A` and `B` are two real symmetric matrices. `B` is positive semi definite.(in practice, positive definite)

Looks like `dgeev`/`dsygv` is the right tool, http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/d9/d8e/group__double_g_eeigen_ga66e19253344358f5dee1e60502b9e96f.html http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/d2/d8a/group__double_s_yeigen_ga007d33bcdcc697e17c6d15432f159b73.html

As an initial step, I would to see if `dgeev`/`dsygv` can reproduce the problem for standard eigenvalue problem, namely when `B` is a unit matrix, by comparing with `dsyev`. However, I got different eigenvectors. Here is my `fortran` code

```
Program eigen_test

  integer, parameter :: dp = selected_real_kind(15, 307)  

  real(dp) :: A(2,2), B(2,2),  work(2), w(2), wr(2), wi(2), vl(2,2), vr(2)
  integer :: i,j,N, info, lwork, LDA, LDB, LDVL, LDVR, ITYPE
  character :: jobz, uplo, JOBVL, JOBVR
  external dsyev, dgeev, DSYGV
  
  N = 2 

  jobz = "V"
  uplo = "U"
  lwork = 6 * N
    
  A(1,1) = 1.0_dp
  A(1,2) = 0.2_dp
  A(2,2) = 1.0_dp
  A(2,1) = A(1,2)  

  B(1,1) = 1.0_dp
  B(1,2) = 0.0_dp
  B(2,2) = 1.0_dp
  B(2,1) = B(1,2)

    
  JOBVL = 'N'
  JOBVR = 'V'
  LDA = N
  LDB = N
  LDVL = N
  LDVR = N

  write (*,*) 'before dsyev', A  
  call dsyev(jobz, uplo, N,  A, N, w, work, lwork, info)
  write (*,*) 'after A dsyev', A 

  A(1,1) = 1.0_dp
  A(1,2) = 0.2_dp
  A(2,2) = 1.0_dp
  A(2,1) = A(1,2)

  write (*,*) 'A before dgeev', A  
  call dgeev(JOBVL, JOBVR, N, A, LDA, WR, WI, VL, LDVL, VR, LDVR, WORK, LWORK, INFO)
  write (*,*) 'A after dgeev', A  
  write (*,*) 'VR',VR 

  A(1,1) = 1.0_dp
  A(1,2) = 0.2_dp
  A(2,2) = 1.0_dp
  A(2,1) = A(1,2)

  B(1,1) = 1.0_dp
  B(1,2) = 0.0_dp
  B(2,2) = 1.0_dp
  B(2,1) = B(1,2)

  write (*,*) 'A before DSYGV', A  
  ITYPE = 1
  call DSYGV(ITYPE, JOBZ, UPLO,  N,  A, LDA, B, LDB, W, WORK, LWORK,  INFO) 
  write (*,*) 'A after DSYGV', A  

end program eigen_test
```

By `gfortran eigen.f90 -L/opt/OpenBLAS/lib -lopenblas`, (I tried to call it from `lopenblas`), I got

```
 after A dsyev   6.4512101403162237E-003 -0.99997919072734975      -0.99997919072734975       -6.4512101403162237E-003
 A before dgeev   1.0000000000000000       0.20000000000000001       0.20000000000000001        1.0000000000000000
 A after dgeev   1.2000000000000000        0.0000000000000000        0.0000000000000000       0.79999999999999993
 VR  0.70710678118654746       0.70710678118654746
 A before DSYGV   1.0000000000000000       0.20000000000000001       0.20000000000000001        1.0000000000000000
 A after DSYGV   6.4512101403162237E-003 -0.99997919072734975      -0.99997919072734975       -6.4512101403162237E-003
```

I expect the eigenvector to be `-0.70710678118654746       0.70710678118654746` or  `0.70710678118654746       0.70710678118654746`, which can be verified from https://www.emathhelp.net/calculators/linear-algebra/eigenvalue-and-eigenvector-calculator/?i=%5B%5B1%2C0.2%5D%2C%5B0.2%2C1%5D%5D

but it is similar to the result from `dgeev`, not `dsyev` or `DSYGV`. My question is, why `dsyev` and `DSYGV` provide different results? Should I somehow input in an upper triangle type of array `A`?

Comment: Your work array is not correctly sized. Changing the dimension to 12 to make it consistent with what you use for lwork gives consistent results across the 3 routines. I strongly suggest using the `size` intrinsic to generate the array size arguments for LAPACK, that will at least let LAPACK flag when you get it wrong.

Comment: Thank you so much! Before introducing `size`, just what do you mean by " Changing the dimension to 12 "? `lwork = 6 * N` will equal 12.

Comment: I see. The dimension of `work`!, http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/d2/d8a/group__double_s_yeigen_ga442c43fca5493590f8f26cf42fed4044.html

          WORK is DOUBLE PRECISION array, dimension (MAX(1,LWORK))
          On exit, if INFO = 0, WORK(1) returns the optimal LWORK.` , if I set to `work(12)` it will get the right results!

Comment: You have dimensioned the work array to be of size 2. That is too small. If you make it 12 the program works as you expect. lwork is suppsoed to be the size of the work array. In the above program it is not. Better to use `Size( work )` as the lwork argument as then you *know* it is consistent. If you do that in the above code LAPACK tells you the size is wrong.